# Python Listener Method with "self"

Tags: python, listener, observer-pattern

All of the listener implementation examples I can find use listener methods without `self`, which seems to be unhelpful if you want to do something with the response outside of the passed listener method.

Here is what I am trying:

```
class A:
    @property
    def command(self):
        return self._command

    @command.setter
    def command(self, command):
        self._command = command
        self._notify_command_observers(command)

    _command_callbacks = []
    def _notify_command_observers(self, command):
        for callback in self._command_callbacks:
            callback(command) #<-- TypeError: function takes 2 positional arguments but 1 were given

    def register_command_callback(self, callback):
        self._command_callbacks.append(callback)

    def receive_command(self, new_command):
        self.command = new_command #<-- an external process will provide this "new_command" variable
```

```
class B:
    def use_command(self, command):
        print(command)

    def command_listener(self, command):
        self.use_command(command)

    a = A()
    a.register_command_callback(command_listener)
```

This results in the error shown in the comment above.

If I use `self` in calling `callback()` inside `_notify_command_observers`, the wrong context is passed and `use_command()` will not be found.

Of course I could remove `self` in `command_listener()`, but I need to access other methods and variables in the `class B` instance.

TL;DR: How do I pass a listener method to a class instance and include the context of the passing class in that listener?

---------- EDIT ----------

Using @jasonharper's suggestion, this works:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.a.register_command_callback(self.command_listener)

    def use_command(self, command):
        print(command)

    def command_listener(self, command):
        self.use_command(command)
```

Comment: You are, for some strange reason, creating your `A()` instance and registering a listener from the body of `B`, rather than an instance of `B()`.  In that context, `command_listener` is not a "method" in any meaningful sense, and there will be no implicit value provided for its `self` parameter.

Comment: @jasonharper that's it! I added those to the class B initializer and it works. If you can add a quick answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks!